# How to copy specific cells from one sheet to another meting if criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm brand new to VBA.

I want to copy specific cells from one sheet to another based on a criteria.
For instance if in the range of H2:H1000 value = "Yes" then copy cells from column A,B,C and D from same row where the criteria meets to another sheet.

My code is just a scratch from what I managed to do, I don't know how to select the cells from the same row where the criteria meets.

```
Sub FindandCopy()

    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim cell As Range


    Set rngA = Sheets("OFCE").Range("H2:H1000")
    For Each cell In rngA
        If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("Dashboard").Range("I2").End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't think you need VBA for this. You can achieve this with formulas. To start with, have a look at `VLookUp` and expand from there

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Which error do you get and where? • I guess it is because you copy a `EntireRow` and try to paste it in column `I` but an entire row doesn't fit behind column `I` it only fits if you past it in column A because the amount of columns is limited.

Comment: look at `AutoFilter` and `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` methods

Comment: Zac a Vlookup would not work properly because the criteria column is at the right...

Comment: PeH that is the problem , idk any other method

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using v-lookup or a simple sumif function. You can do this outside of vba, in the sheet itself, or you can program it into your existing macro.

Comment: Even with my column criteria at the right of what i want to lookup?

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of material online on this so you should be able to solve it.

I used offset (to get from H to A) and resize (to expand A to A-D) and then copy to the first unused row of I on the other sheet.

You don't need to Select/Activate, in fact it's [discouraged](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjQwq2D3bvgAhVytHEKHfqODsoQFjACegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F10714251%2Fhow-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba&usg=AOvVaw1go_Alxw25oWPFl6A_xvZB).

```
Sub FindandCopy()

Dim rngA As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rngA = Sheets("OFCE").Range("H2:H1000")

For Each cell In rngA
    If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
        cell.Offset(, -7).Resize(, 4).Value.Copy _
             Sheets("Dashboard").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

---

However, rather than a loop, you should consider using AutoFilter or Find to do this as they are more efficient.

Comment: Thank you very much SJR, i’ll try this tomorrow at the office. Also will do some research on AutoFilter or Find